# Tabbed view controller, scrollToItem in collection view not working after switching tabs

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a tabbed bar view controller. The main view controller has a collection view. I want to animate a list of cells that are contained in an array like so:

```
// Called in viewDidAppear
func animateNewAchievements() {
        if let indexPath = newAchievementIndexPaths.first {
            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
// Delegate method
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if let indexPath = newAchievementIndexPaths.first {
            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TrophyCollectionViewCell {
                cell.animate(completion: {
                    if self.newAchievementIndexPaths.count > 0 {
                        self.newAchievementIndexPaths.removeFirst()
                    }
                   self.perform(#selector(self.animateNewAchievements), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.4)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see if will cycle through the index paths in `newAchievementIndexPaths` one by one. This all works very well however if I interrupt the process and switch tabs and return to the view controller the animation will not continue. It calls `collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)` but it doesn't animate and the delegate isn't called. However if I scroll the table very slightly with my finger and leave and return to the screen it will resume the animation without any issues.

Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: this is happening because you are already at the cell for that index path.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the collection view isn't programmatically scrolling when you switch view controllers.

Just try adding this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let indexPath = newAchievementIndexPaths[1] {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This way you scroll back to that item in `viewDidAppear` when you return back to this view controller.